# MYSQL - copy tables with specific prefix between databases

Tags: mysql

Is there a SQL command to copy many tables with specific prefix (ie `yot_`) between two MYSQL databases? The DB user has access to both of the DB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no SQL statement of any kind that operates on tables using wildcards. You must name tables explicitly.

You can, however, *generate* the statements by querying the INFORMATION_SCHEMA:

```
SELECT CONCAT(
  'RENAME TABLE my_old_schema.`', TABLE_NAME, '` '
  ' TO my_new_schema.`', TABLE_NAME, '`;'
) AS _stmt
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE 'yot\_%'
AND TABLE_SCHEMA='my_old_schema';
```

That's an example of generating a series of RENAME TABLE statements, which will move the tables from one schema to another. But it demonstrates the technique

You can try to make table-copy instead of move, with `CREATE TABLE new_table LIKE old_table;` followed by `INSERT INTO new_table SELECT * FROM old_table;`

Comment: Any way to execute the result of the SELECT right away?

Comment: The output of the query I showed above is a series of SQL statements. You can execute those statements one by one, or you can save them to a file and then run that file as input to the `mysql` tool as if it were any other SQL script.